# Adding tags: Django custom form widget for ManyToMany model field

Tags: python, django, model, widget, tagging

I am currently creating my own Tagging app for Django.

Here are the models:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

I created a form for my model `Book` and a widget for `Tag` inputs:

```
class BookForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('title', 'tags')
        widgets = {
            'tags': TagWidget
        }

class TagWidget(Widget):
    """
    Widget for Tag input fields.
    """
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        final_attrs = self.build_attrs(attrs, name=name)
        final_attrs['class'] = 'tag-input'
        options = []

        # TODO the following tags should be assigned from the model directly
        options.append('tag1');
        options.append('tag2');

        list_element = u'<ul%s>' % flatatt(final_attrs)
        return mark_safe(list_element + '\n<li>' + (u'</li>\n<li>'.join(options)) + '</li>\n</ul>')
```

### Questions

1. How can i add the currently existing tags to the options array (`options.append(...)`)?
2. Also, how can i improve the creation of the html code (see last line `mark_safe`)? I'd like to put all html code somewhere else (preferably in my templates folder).

Comment: Tag.name should be initialized with (unique=True, db_index=True).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can pass additional data in widget's constructor. Something like

   ```
   class TagWidget(Widget):
       def __init__(self, initial_tags, *args, **kwargs)
           self.initial_tags = initial_tags
           super(TagWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

   # ...

   widgets = {
       'tags': TagWidget(initial_tags=('one', 'two', 'three'))
   }
   ```

   Then the data will be accessible in `self.initial_tags`.
2. You can use [render_to_string](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#the-render-to-string-shortcut) function.

Comment: how can i automatically tell which tags a model has? `initial_tags=('one', 'two', 'three')` must be dynamically assigned depending on the tags assigned to this object

Comment: @Alp render(self, name, **value**, attrs=None)